# preferredStatusBarStyle not respecting on iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working in my simulator on a single view app with a dark background. It's a UIViewController wrapped in a UINavigationController.

In my view controller I have `override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle { .lightContent }`

In my info.plist I have `View controller-based status bar appearance = YES`

And yet when I run it it shows white for a second and then jumps to having black text.

What's going on here? Is there a fix?

Edit: I've tried `.default`, `.lightContent` and `.darkContent` just to be sure, nothing works

Comment: This has nothing to do with iOS 13. Overriding `preferredStatusBarStyle` when you're wrapped in a navigation controller has _never_ been the right way.

Comment: Can you leave your comment as an answer and I'll mark as correct? Thanks Matt

Comment: No thanks. I’ve dealt with this at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58210536/ios-13-setting-status-bar-text-color-from-within-uinavigationcontroller/ and https://stackoverflow.com/a/52457515/341994.

Comment: Thank you @Matt this the correct answer and good explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/52457515/341994

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I recently ran into this problem and these extensions seemed to fix the issue.

```swift
extension UITabBarController {
    open override var childForStatusBarStyle: UIViewController? {
        return selectedViewController?.childForStatusBarStyle ?? selectedViewController
    }
}

extension UINavigationController {
    open override var childForStatusBarStyle: UIViewController? {
        return topViewController?.childForStatusBarStyle ?? topViewController
    }
}
```

I just put them into a file called `UIViewController+StatusBar.swift` and included it in the project.

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to edit my question to mention my VC is in a UINavigationController so your second extension did the trick. I've seen this question a few other times in relation to the tab bar

Comment: This is wrong. The way to change the status bar style when you have a navigation bar is to set the navigation bar's `barStyle`. See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/52457515/341994

Answer (score 3):

The correct answer referenced by @matt is `navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .lightContent` in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: It's not `.lightContent` but `.black` if you want a white status bar. `UIBarStyle.lightContent`doesn't exist.