# preferredStatusBarStyle not getting called in iOS 13 and other

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar, ios13

I have multiple `UITabBar` in my application and some `ViewController` has White color statusbar and some `ViewController` has black color statusbar.

My `info.plist`

`View controller-based status bar appearance` to `YES`

My Viewcontroller has below code.

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .default //or return . lightContent
}
```

but `preferredStatusBarStyle` never getting called.

i have also written below line in my controller `viewDidLoad` but still above wasn't getting called.

`self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()`

also i have changeed  `controller-based status bar appearance` to `YES` && `NO` for multiple time to check but nothing helps to me.

I have also tried below solutions and other stackoverflow answers but nothing helps me.

[preferredStatusBarStyle not respecting on iOS 13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58203902/preferredstatusbarstyle-not-respecting-on-ios-13)

[preferredStatusBarStyle var not working in iOS12?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52452979/preferredstatusbarstyle-var-not-working-in-ios12/52457515#52457515)

## EDIT

I have tried below code which returns me the `topViewController` and it will call the `preferredStatusBarStyle` of that `ViewController`

```
extension UINavigationController {
    override open var childForStatusBarStyle: UIViewController? {
        return topViewController
    }
}
```

so once the `topViewController` found it will call `preferredStatusBarStyle` of that particular `ViewController`.

but the issue is that it wasn't getting called inside `UITabBarController` -> `UINavigationController` -> `UIViewController`.

## Requirment

I have 2 different `TabBarController`.

1st `TabBarController` statusBarStyle is `.lightContent`.

2nd `TabBarController` statusBarStyle is `.lightContent` and `.default` in different controller.

When i change to the 2nd TabBarController it will call `preferredStatusBarStyle` of 2nd `TabBarController` and all `ViewController` statusBarStyle goes `.default` but some of my controller statusBarStyle wants to be of `.ligthContent`

How can i achieve this?

any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I still use UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle though it was deprecated, but it still works correctly, call it in viewWillAppear

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik, okay let me try it.

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik, My flow like this. `TabBarController`--> `NavigationController`--> `ViewController`.

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik, i put above line in `ViewController` `viewWillAppear` then proper statusBar style display for 1 second and then it goes to .light automatically.

Comment: remove from plist `controller-based status bar appearance` call `UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .default
        setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()` in viewWillAppear

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik, If i remove `controller-based status bar appearance` then do i need to write `UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .default`/ `.lightContent` in all `ViewController`?

Comment: in my case I created two controllers for light and dark style and inherite controllers from them

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik, i do the same for `UINavigationController`. 1 is for light and 2nd is for default but sometimg style goes worng

Comment: @Kuldeep if your status bar shows correct for 1 sec then goes back to .light in 1 sec, it looks like you have some code somewhere in ```viewDidAppear``` for any of your view controllers/navigationControllers/tabBarControllers. Check if any of these implement anything in their ```viewDidAppear``` method.

Comment: try something like this. Target->general->StatusBarStyle->default. It may work

Comment: check with disabled dark mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i got the solution.

Put below code to find the `topViewController`.

```
extension UINavigationController {
    override open var childForStatusBarStyle: UIViewController? {
        return topViewController
    }
}
```

so once it finds `topViewController`, below code getting called in your current `ViewController` and you can set `statusBarStyle` as per requirement.

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle { }
```

In my case i have 2 `TabBar`.

1st `TabBar` controllers are of `.lightContent` and 2nd `TabBar` controllers are of `.default` so create 2 `UITabBarController`. 1st is for `.lightContent` and 2nd is for `.default` and put `preferredStatusBarStyle` inside it.

so when you are at `UITabBarController` sub controller, your `UITabBarController` `preferredStatusBarStyle` getting called and sub controller `statusBarStyle` set as per your set style.

Comment: where should i put the extension? in the view controller. oc create a new file as extension ? Because still not working on me

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with iOS 13. You just have the rules wrong.

In a navigation controller situation, the color of the status bar is not determined by the view controller’s preferredStatusBarStyle.

It is determined, amazingly, by the navigation bar’s barStyle. To get light status bar text, say (in your view controller):

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
```

Answer (score 1):

please refer to this

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621453-modalpresentationcapturesstatusb

```
override var modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance: Bool {
        set {}
        get{

            return true
        }
    }
```

Comment: this will give an error like : Cannot override mutable property with read-only property 'modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance'

Comment: i have updated i don't know how it missed that you need to call set and get both.

Comment: will you please write sample code like how can i change statusbar style through this?

Comment: did you write above method and it gets called? where preferredStatusBarStyle was n't working. if you check you will see the case where preferredsta ytsubarstyle will n't called is presentation case. If it does n't work can send me code or screenshot i can help you with that.

Answer (score -2):

### ***`the following may be of assistance to you;`***

> **For developer guidance, see the *[UIStatusBarStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistatusbarstyle)* constant in
>   *[UIApplicenter code hereation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication)* and the *[preferredStatusBarStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621416-preferredstatusbarstyle)*
>   property in *[UIViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller)*.**