# What is the correct way to manage statusBarStyle in Swift?

Tags: swift, statusbar, ios13, swift5

I've tried adding key `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to true inside info.plist file and then added the below code inside `UINavigationController` class which holds several `UIViewController` classes.

```
class HomeNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }
}
```

But, it did not work.

I've also tried setting the `barStyle` property of `navigationBar` to `.black` but that too didn't work either.

Also looked up to https://stackoverflow.com/a/58203998/9180494, but that did not help as well.

Please NOTE: For `UIViewController` classes not embedded inside any `UINavigationController` , if I use computed property `preferredStatusBarStyle`, then it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try in `viewDidAppear()` of `UINavigationController` class:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
}
```

Also add (in the same class as above):

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Anuranjan Bose Try this on your view did load,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}
```