# Status Bar Style issues since Xcode 11.4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

Since Xcode 11.4 overriding the `preferredStatusBarStyle` property does not seem to work anymore in some cases.

We have an extension of `UINavigationController` where we override it for basically every ViewController but this property is no longer called since Xcode 11.4. Therefore the status bar is black for mostly all ViewControllers.

```
extension UINavigationController {

    override open var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }

}
```

It also stopped working for some ViewControllers where we override `preferredStatusBarStyle` again. The property gets accessed, however, the status bar does not change its color.

`View controller-based status bar appearance` is set to `YES` in info.plist.

Issue occurs on simulator and real devices.

Does anyone have this problem too?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38213286/overriding-methods-in-swift-extensions

Comment: Jut sub class NavigationController and then override and use it!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a solution. Looks like I need to set the barStyle of the navigationBar to `.black` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52457515/3940665)

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
```

Not sure though why this is necessary now.

The `UINavigationController` extension is no longer needed then.

Answer (score 0):

change the  UIStatusBarStyle  in appdelegates in this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
         
        return true
    }
```