# Status Bar Content colour not changing to white in navigation controller using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, statusbar

I have used UINavigationController to create navigation flow, first screen is List view controller and second one is detail view controller of list item.

I am hiding navigation bar in both view controllers because I have created my own top bar.

Now I am trying to change status bar content to light content but

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle{
   .lightContent
}
```

This is not getting called. I read multiple answers about changing status bar content style when UINavigationController is used but none of them help because I am hiding navigation bar.

Navigation controller is embedded in TabBarController.

Attaching the image for reference
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCxO2.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [preferredStatusBarStyle var not working in iOS12?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52452979/preferredstatusbarstyle-var-not-working-in-ios12)

Comment: No I am hiding the navigation bar so can't use this approach. Thanks for the reply though

Comment: Have you tried the second answer? It has nothing to do with navigation bar

Comment: Yes I tried 2nd approach as well but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

First hide navigation bar in **viewDidLoad()** by hit the below code

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
```

Add the status bar code in **ViewController** like you did

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle{
   return .lightContent
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am already hiding the navigation bar and then overriding the status bar style. This is not working control doesn't reach there at all.